# How to manage shared resources for several web apps in Maven AND Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

*Note: I didn't get any response in the first version of this question, so I modified it to be more generic...*

**Context**

My project is divided into several maven modules and several web-applications. Here is the structure:

```
my-project
  + pom.xml
  +-- commons
  +-- persistence
  +-- ...
  +-- web-app-1
  +-- web-app-2
  +-- ...
```

All the web applications share common resources, such as JS, CSS and images files.

Instead of duplicating these resources in each `web-app-X`, I decided to create another project called `web-resources`, which is a WAR project.
The structure is then the following one:

```
my-project
  + pom.xml
  +-- commons
  +-- persistence
  +-- ...
  +-- web-app-1
  +-- web-app-2
  +-- ...
  +-- web-resources
       +-- pom.xml
       +-- src/main/webapp
            +-- web.xml (which is almost empty, just need to be present for Maven)
            +-- web_resources
                 +-- css
                 +-- images
                 +-- javascript
```

---

**Maven**

In Maven 2 (or Maven 3, as I just migrated my project to maven 3.0.2), this configuration is easy to manage as all `web-app-X` declare `web-resources` as a dependency:

```
<groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>web-app-1</artifactId>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-resources</artifactId>
        <version>${preclosing-version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

So when I build my WAR project, it first get the `web-resources.war` (built just before), unzip it, and build *on top of it* the `web-app-X` web-application.
This way, my WAR file will contains also a directory called `web-resources/` that contains the shared resources.

This is the war overlay principle.

So on a Maven point of view, everything is fine!

---

**Eclipse**

Now, here comes the main problem: having a good Eclipse configuration.

*Question*: How can I use my current configuration to be managed correctly by Eclipse? In particular, when I deploy any `web-app-X` in Tomcat using Eclipse...

Note that I want to get the more automatizable (?) configuration, and avoid any manual steps, as this configuration should be used by dozens of developers...

For me, the best solution seems to use the *linked resources* of Eclipse. Thus, I set the following configuration in my `web-app-X` pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                <linkedResources>
                    <linkedResource>
                        <name>web_resources</name>
                        <type>2</type>
                        <location>${project.basedir}\..\web-resources\src\main\webapp\web_resources</location>
                    </linkedResource>
                </linkedResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

When I run the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` configuration, it adds succesfully this information in my `.project` file:

```
<projectDescription>
  ...
  <linkedResources>
    <link>
      <name>web_resources</name>
      <type>2</type>
      <location>C:\dev\project\web-resources\src\main\webapp\web_resources</location>
    </link>
  </linkedResources>
<projectDescription>
```

Now, I import my project in Eclipse.
Problem: in `Project properties > Java Build Path > Source`, I don't see the Link Source present.
I only see my four Maven default directories (`src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`).
What is strange is that when I try to manually add the linked resources, it refuses and says that it already exists...

So when I deploy my web application on my Tomcat in Eclipse, it does *not* deploy the web_resources directory, and thus I don't get the CSS / JS / images deployed.

After some tests, it seems that I have to do two modifications:

1. Add the line `<classpathentry kind="src" path="web_resources" output="src/main/webapp/web_resources"/>` in my `.classpath` file;
2. Remove the `<project>preclosing-web-resources</project>` in the `.project` file.

Note that using this configuration, Eclipse will copy (and keep synchronization) the content of web_resources project in my `web-app-X/src/main/webapp/web_resources`, but this is not a problem (this directory is ignored by the SCM).

The only automated solution I found was to create a simple Maven plugin that do the two previous modification, and then run the following command (or use a .bat file):

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse myEclipsePlugin:eclipse
```

---

**Question**

- Is there a better way to manage such configuration?

---

*Technical information*

Java 6, Maven 3.0.2, maven eclipse plugin 2.8, Eclipse 3.3.2 (but I can test with newer version of Eclipse), **no** m2eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Servlet 3.0, you can share resources by putting them within the src/main/resources/META-INF/resources directory.

When the webapp deploys, Servlet 3.0 makes those resources available from the context path.  For example, in your case...

```
web-resources
-- src
---- main
------ resources
-------- META-INF
---------- resources
------------ css
-------------- global.css
------------ images
-------------- background.png
```

Let's assume that **my_project** has a dependency on **web-resources** and is deployed to the url http://my.localhost:8080/myProject.

With that configuration, the following URLs will resolve to the correct resources:

- http://my.localhost:8080/myProject/css/global.css
- http://my.localhost:8080/myProject/images/background.png

**IF** you have a name conflict between the resources and your actual application, the application will win.

Be sure your web.xml states you are using Servlet 3.0

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this blog post.  It covers a method for sharing resources using maven:

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/