# Is there a way to add a custom line in .classpath using mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Tags: maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I am using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command to generate my `.project` and `.classpath`.

However, for some reasons, I want to add one line in the `.classpath` file. Is there a configuration in my `pom.xml` that I can use to achieve that?

Note that `<additionalConfig>` cannot be used, as this will erase the content of the `.classpath`.

I am using maven 3.0.2 and maven-eclipse-plugin 2.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what that line is.

1. If it's a source folder, use the
   [buildhelper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin) to
   [add a source folder](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) in a
   lifecycle phase before
   `generate-sources`, this will
   automatically be picked up by the
   eclipse plugin.
2. If it's a classpath container, you
   can use the [classpathContainers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#classpathContainers)
   parameter
3. If you want to change the output folders (from `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` to something else), change them in the maven build configuration:

   ```
   <build>
       <!-- replace "target" -->
       <directory>somedir</directory>
       <!-- replace "target/classes" -->
       <outputDirectory>anotherdir</outputDirectory>
       <!-- replace "target/test-classes" -->
       <testOutputDirectory>yetanotherdir</testOutputDirectory>
   </build>
   ```

   You can configure each of those three independently, and the changes will be picked up by the eclipse plugin, but it's considered good practice to put `outputDirectory` and `testOutputDirectory` inside `directory` (usually by referencing `${project.build.directory}`), otherwise you break standard functionality like `mvn clean` (it cleans `${project.build.directory}`):

   ```
   <build>
       <directory>bin</directory>
       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/main-classes
       </outputDirectory>
       <!-- this config will replace "target" with "bin",
            compile src/main/java to "bin/main-classes"
            and compile src/test/java to "bin/test-classes"
            (because the default config for <testOutputDirectory> is
            ${project.build.directory}/test-classes )
       -->
   </build>
   ```

**Reference:**

- [POM Reference > Build > The BaseBuild Element Set](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element)
- [POM Reference > Build > Directories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Directories)
- [Introduction to the POM > Available Variables](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables)

---

**Update:** in your case I guess the only possible solution is to programmatically edit the `.classpath` file. What I would probably do is something like this:

1. Define a `<profile>` named eclipse (or whatever)
2. Define an execution of the [gmaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) (use [this version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.gmaven/gmaven-plugin/1.3))
3. Write a short groovy script (inline in the pom or external) that checks the .classpath file for your classpath container and adds it if missing (bind execution to a lifecycle phase, e.g. `generate-resources`)
4. set the [profile activation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation) to `<file><exists>${project.basedir}/.classpath</exists></file>` (because you only want it to be active in an eclipse project)

The problem with this solution: `eclipse:eclipse` is a goal, not a phase, so it's not possible to execute this automatically, so you'll have to do something like this:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse    # two separate executions
mvn generate-resources # here, profile will be active
```

or perhaps this will also work:

```
mvn -Peclipse eclipse:eclipse generate-resources
```

Comment: It's the 3rd option :) In fact my line is a `<classpathentry/>` with specific information (such as an `output` information), so these plugins do not seem to have the adequate configuration...

Comment: @Sean Thanks, I know quite well Maven in fact, but this is not what I want. If you want to understand the complete problem, see my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956245/how-to-manage-linked-resources-in-eclipse-for-correct-tomcat-deployment

Comment: @Sean, indeed, this solution is not really nice (thanks anyway). In fact, I already solved my issue in creating a little Maven plugin that is run just after the `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, which edits the `.classpath` file. But I wanted to find a way to only use the `maven-eclipse-plugin`.

Comment: @romaintaz yup, the only way to do it in one step is to let your plugin extend the `eclipse:eclipse` plugin goal.

Comment: @romaintaz thanks. and my answer is essentially the same as what you did, just that I proposed an inline groovy solution whereas you used a custom plugin to do the same thing